# Access data from inner class

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to update a `TextView`:

```
if(free != "") {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_TripStartStatus)).append(free + " are not free");
        }
    });
}
```

It gives me error saying that it needs to be declared `final`. I can create a function accepting `final` free variable and use that. However is there any one liner that I can use here?

Comment: declare `free` `globally`

Comment: Make variable final

Answer (score 2):

Just create a temporary `final` variable outside the inner class:

```
if(free!="") {  // this is the wrong way to compare strings
    final String tempFree = free;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_TripStartStatus)).append(tempFree + " are not free");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This one is promising to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not want a separate method,

1. You can use the solution as suggested by [shmosle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553851/shmosel).
2. If possible, you can declare the variable `free` at enclosing class level.

Answer (score -1):

*but it may throw NullPointerException in case of activity finish.
first check whether current activity is still working or not.*

```
 private void appendText(final String free) {

        if(this.isFinishing()||free.equals(""))
            return;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).append(free + " are not free");
                }
            });
        }
```

**or** if you don't want to use method then use

```
if(this.isFinishing()||free.equals(""))
            return;

          final String temp=free;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).append(temp + " are not free");
                }
            });
```